# What can I do when my dog loves going out at night?

Tags: dogs, behavior

I have a male dog who has recently developed the habit of going out at night. I followed him once and I noticed he usually goes to meet a female dog at another house.

I have been chaining him since, but this is not helping as he cries all night.

What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say that in this case, try not letting the dog go out at night. It may cost you a few nights sleep, but eventually the dog will learn that going out at night isn't allowed.

Make sure to take the dog out right before "bed" time so that the dog doesn't resort to going inside the house in anger.

Also, crating the dog at night may be an option if the behavior doesn't stop.

Comment: Be prepared for an [extinction burst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction_burst#Extinction_burst). Your dog has learned that it will get out at night if it cries. If that doesn't work anymore, it will cry louder and longer before it will give up on that particular behaviour. The problem is, if you cave in to its insistence, you've just made the problem 10 times worse, because now it knows that it will get its way if it just cries loud/long enough.